# Trying to remove one label from facet_grid, but it shows up at NA. How can I get rid of this label all together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to produce a bar graph with facet_grid to show my main categorical variable ("Whereabouts"), with my subcategory ("Thingies") plotted on the bar graph. However, I would like to completely remove the label for "Dead," since it is redundant and a bit distracting. Does anyone know I could achieve this?

As a side note, I also noticed that fat_relevel does not seem to be cooperating here. Any insight there, as well?

Here is my initial code and figure that displays the issue:

```
SpookyReport2 <-  HalloweenData %>% mutate(Whereabouts = fct_relevel(Whereabouts, c("Dead", "Halfdead", "Alive"))) %>% 
  ggplot(HalloweenData, mapping = aes(x=Thingies, y=TotalSpook, fill= Thingies)) +
  geom_bar(stat='summary') +
  geom_beeswarm(aes(x = Thingies, y = TotalSpook), dodge.width = 0.9, alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(data = SpookySumReport2, aes(x = Thingies, y = mean.cm, ymin=mean.cm-SE.cm,ymax=mean.cm+SE.cm, colour=Thingies),
                color = 'black', width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=SpookyPalette) +
  facet_grid(~ Whereabouts, 
             scales = "free_x",
             space = "free_x",
             switch = "x")+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, units = "cm"), 
        strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y="Total spook (spook-o-meters)", x=NULL) + ggtitle("Effect of losing my mind over this") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) 
SpookyReport2
```

[image: Bad graph]

So, I looked all over this website for advice and decided to go the labeller route. I thought this would allow me to remove the "Dead" label, but instead it produced an even more annoying "NA" in its place.

```
where.labs <- c("Dead", "Halfdead", "Alive")
names(where.labs) <- c("", "Halfdead" , "Alive")


SpookyReport2 <-  HalloweenData %>% mutate(Whereabouts = fct_relevel(Whereabouts, c("Dead", "Halfdead", "Alive"))) %>% 
  ggplot(HalloweenData, mapping = aes(x=Thingies, y=TotalSpook, fill= Thingies)) +
  geom_bar(stat='summary') +
  geom_beeswarm(aes(x = Thingies, y = TotalSpook), dodge.width = 0.9, alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(data = SpookySumReport2, aes(x = Thingies, y = mean.cm, ymin=mean.cm-SE.cm,ymax=mean.cm+SE.cm, colour=Thingies),
                color = 'black', width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=SpookyPalette) +
  facet_grid(~ Whereabouts, 
             scales = "free_x",
             space = "free_x",
             switch = "x",
labeller = labeller(Whereabouts = where.labs))+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, units = "cm"), 
        strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y="Total spook (spook-o-meters)", x=NULL) + ggtitle("Effect of losing my mind over this") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) 
SpookyReport2
```

[image: Annoying NA on x-axis]

Does anybody have a solution for this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use “” rather than NA.

Comment: I believe that is what I tried in the example above - that is how I ended up with NA.

Comment: Change the levels vector of Thingies from “Dead” to “”.  If you posted the output of `levels()` for that variable, I’m sure someone can give you the code, although it’s probably been asked and answered tens of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alternative version of `Whereabouts` where “Dead”
is replaced with an empty string `""`.

Here is a minimal example to demonstrate the idea

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = sample(letters, 200, replace = TRUE),
  b = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 200, replace = TRUE)
)

df <-
  df |>
  mutate(b2 = ifelse(b == "C", "", b))

ggplot(df, aes(a)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid( ~ b2)
```

[image]

The code for your data to make the changes would look like this:

```
HalloweenData <- 
  HalloweenData |> 
  mutate(Whereabouts2 = ifelse(Whereabouts == "Dead", "", Whereabouts))
```

Comment: Thank you for that example! Unfortunately, I am a bit code-dumb. Would you be able to provide that example but using variables in my data? For example, is this what you mean? However, I am unsure what variables would replace b and C in your example. HalloweenData <-
  HalloweenData |>
  mutate(Whereabouts = ifelse(b == "C", "", b))

Comment: I added an example that should work in your environment.